# How to get the difference between the chosen date and 1 month before in SQL

Tags: sql

How to calculate the price difference between the chosen date and 1 month before.
Example if user chooses 2/1(Feb 1), it will return the difference between 2/1(Feb 1) and 1/1(Jan 1). This is in SQL and data is daily. Date column has YYYY-MM-DD format.

Sample layout:

Date (YYYY-MM-DD) , Product Name (text), Price (int)

Comment: Which database are you using?  What happens on March 31, since February has no 31st day?

Comment: Well, the difference is constant and equals to one month...

Comment: Should be the last of the month. So March 31 against Feb 28.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: OT a (date) format implies text and you did store it as date, I hope?

Comment: Yes, stored as date

Comment: Is there only one row for date?

Comment: No, there's 1 row for each day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-join for this. This query uses the same table twice - `t_now` includes prices this month; `t_then` shows last month's prices.

In the standard SQL you can write this

```
SELECT t_now.product, t_now.price - t_then.price
  FROM prices t_now JOIN
       prices t_then ON (t_now.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH = t_then.date
                     AND t_now.product=t_then.product)     
WHERE t_now.date='2018-05-01'
```

It works in MySQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f208c5/4
You will need changes to the month calculation for SQL Server - You can use DATEADD(MONTH, -1 date)

If you have many prices per month there will be there will be multiple answers at the end of a short month. There are four days one month before 28<sup>th</sup> Feb - namely 28<sup>th</sup> Jan, 29<sup>th</sup> Jan, 30<sup>th</sup> Jan and 31<sup>st</sup> Jan

Input

```
date        product price
2018-05-01  Gadget  100
2018-05-01  Widget  50
2018-04-01  Gadget  20
2018-04-01  Widget  10
```

Output

```
product t_now.price - t_then.price
Gadget  80
Widget  40
```

Comment: Trying to get the difference in price based on the date. I have updated the details.